# Data not being populated in dropdown using sqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource

I need to populate the data from database in Dropdown using sqlDataSource. The SqlDataSource is using a querystring. The data is not being populated in dropdown. Can you please suggest what I am doing wrong here?

Code for Dropdown:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ComboBox ID="SelectDropDown1" runat="server" DropDownStyle="DropDownList"
                    AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Width="200px" Height="16pt"
                    Font-Size="8pt"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Rubric"
                 DataValueField="Rubric">

               <asp:ListItem Value="all">All</asp:ListItem>

                </ajaxToolkit:ComboBox>
```

Code for SqlDataSource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Education_Data %>"

        SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Rubric] FROM [table1] WHERE ([Program] = @Program)">

        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Program" QueryStringField="Program" 
                Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>

    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Post all code for your SQLDatasource

Comment: @ user1848739 -  editted

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT [Rubric] FROM [table1] WHERE ([Program] = YourRequestQueryString Run this query to your SQL and see if its returning some values. Also try adding SelectCommandType in your SQLDataSource tag

Comment: where program='YourRequestQuerystring'. I believe program's datatype is varchar

Comment: How are you setting the QueryStringParameter? You need to bind it to something or set it somehow using ControlId and PropertyName

Comment: QueryString Program gets it's value from  form-field Evaluation.SelectedItem..


Response.Redirect("Home.aspx?Program=" + Evaluation.SelectedItem);

Comment: @ user1848739 - yes, it is varchar...The tried your method, it didn't work!!

Comment: @rivarolle - Am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure you have returned records when you run the selectcommand to your SQL management studio. I believe something might be wrong when you pass the querystring.

Answer (score 0):

The @program needs to be set somehow.

This [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1kdt8w2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) article will show you how to do it. Go to section "Passing Parameters to SQL Statements"